# perl + delete the line only if match the exactly string in line

Tags: regex, linux, perl

I work on the following file:

```
more file1


name="UAT/CC/Global/MES/UK/adWerum-UK" 
name="UAT/CC/Global/MES/UK/adWerum-UK-Adapter" 
name="UAT/CC/Global/MES/UK/adWerum-UK1" 
name="HOME/UAT/CC/Global/ME/UK/adWerum-UK"
```

I created the following perl command  in order to delete only exactly string with backslashes

```
UAT/CC/Global/ME/UK/adWerum-UK
```

the perl syntax:

```
perl -n -i -e 'print unless m/\Q$ENV{A}\E/' file1
```

the problem is perl removing all lines that contain the line:

```
UAT/CC/Global/ME/UK/adWerum-UK
```

example

```
A=UAT/CC/Global/MES/UK/adWerum-UK
export A=UAT/CC/Global/ME/UK/adWerum-UK
perl -n -i -e 'print unless m/\Q$ENV{A}\E/' file1
```

.

```
more file1

file is empty
```

While the expected results are

```
name="UAT/CC/Global/MES/UK/adWerum-UK-Adapter" 
name="UAT/CC/Global/MES/UK/adWerum-UK1" 
name="HOME/UAT/CC/Global/ME/UK/adWerum-UK"
```

please advise what need to change in my perl syntax in order to remove only the line with the match string between the double quota

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just include the double quotes in the regex pattern?

```
perl -i -ne 'print unless /"\Q$ENV{A}\E"/' file1
```

Comment: I tried it but all lines are printed without delete the relevant line ( my perl version - v5.10.1 )

Comment: @Jogeff: The answer is fine; you've made a mistake in your environment variable. You have `/ME/UK/` instead of `/MES/UK/` in your `export` command.